# Bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: bash

I have the following code that checks whether either of two input args are supplied, and depending on their existance runs a certain piece of code. I'm running into syntax errors in my if statements however, because I'm getting an unexpected token `else' error

```
if [ -z "${4}" ] || [ -z "${5}" ]
then
    echo "Missing index argument(s). Defaulting to entire file."
    cat ${devicesFile} | cut -d "," -f 4 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | awk '{print substr($1,1,8)"-"substr($1,9,4)"-"substr($1,13,4)"-"substr($1,17,4)"-"substr($1,21,12)}' | while read deviceGuid
else
    i1=${4}
    i2=${5}
    head -n ${i1} ${devicesFile} | tail -n ${i2} | cut -d "," -f 4 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | awk '{print substr($1,1,8)"-"substr($1,9,4)"-"substr($1,13,4)"-"substr($1,17,4)"-"substr($1,21,12)}' | while read deviceGuid
fi
```

Is it an issue with my or condition.? That's the only thing I can really think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

//Here's what I had before I tried to add the index parameters, so what HVD said about the broken while makes sense..

```
cat ${devicesFile}  | cut -d "," -f 4 | tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | awk '{print substr($1,1,8)"-"substr($1,9,4)"-"substr($1,13,4)"-"substr($1,17,4)"-"substr($1,21,12)}' | while read deviceGuid
do
    # now=`date +"%Y%m%d %H%M%S"`
    currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`
    currentHour=`date +"%H"`
    currentDate=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
    # create parent directory
    mkdir -p ${crashlogFolder}/${currentDate}/${currentHour}/${crashCode}/
    # create crash log for device
    touch ${crashlogFolder}/${currentDate}/${currentHour}/${crashCode}/${currentTime}_${deviceGuid}.log
done
```

Comment: it's an issue with the broken `while` at the end of that pipeline on the fourth line.

Comment: Always use double quotes around your variable interpolations unless you specifically require the shell to perform token splitting and wildcard expansion on the values.

Comment: if `$devicesFile` is a file on your system, you can replace `cat ${devicesFile} | cut -d "," -f 4` by `cut -d "," -f 4 ${devicesFile}` as `cut` can read from file: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cut.1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lacking a body to your `while` block, it should have the form `while <condition>; do <actions>; done`

```
if [[ -z "${4}" || -z "${5}" ]]; then
    # …
    cat ${devicesFile} \
    | … \
    | while read deviceGuid; do echo $deviceGuid; done
else
    # …
    head -n ${i1} ${devicesFile} \
    | … \
    | while read deviceGuid; do echo $deviceGuid; done
fi
```

### Explaination

1. used bash test `[[ … ]]` so you can use the boolean OR inside as `[[ … || … ]]`, discard if you need portability;
2. replaced some of your command by `…` just for clarity
3. escaped newline, `\` at the end of line (no spaces must follow), to get a clearer script
4. added missing block with dummy `echo $deviceGuid` command.

Comment: Since `|` is not a command terminator, you can end a line with `|` instead of using an explicit line continuation character and starting the next line with `|`.

Comment: @chepner nice, I will try that when using bash in makefile. However I like the way the pipe at the beginning make it look like a thread and a logical continuum.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot mix control structures like that. If you originally had

```
a | while b
do
  c
done
```

and now you want `a` to be customisable, you cannot do

```
if d
then
  e | while b
else
  f | while b
fi
do
  c
done
```

Shells just don't work like that. (Nor do most other languages.) `while b; do c; done` was a single statement, and cannot be broken up like that.

Instead, you should change it to

```
if d
then
  e
else
  f
fi | while b
do
  c
done
```

The whole `if d; then e; else f; fi` is a single statement, and its output, regardless of which of the commands it comes from, will be piped to the `while` statement.

Comment: In addition, you would probably want to refactor the `tr | awk` to outside the `fi` so that you can avoid code repetition.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide a bit more info, I see the issue with the while statement though. Would just simply putting a do block in the then and else statements work.?

Comment: @MrTunaDeluxe Yes, it's possible to copy the `do`...`done` into both branches of the `if` statement, but that would cause even more code duplication, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment on Édouard Lopez's answer: DRY -- pull out all the common code:

```
if [[ -z "${4}" || -z "${5}" ]]; then
    cat ${devicesFile} 
else
    head -n ${i1} ${devicesFile} | tail -n ${i2}
fi |
  cut -d "," -f 4 | 
  tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | 
  awk -F, '{print substr($1,1,8)"-"substr($1,9,4)"-"substr($1,13,4)"-"substr($1,17,4)"-"substr($1,21,12)}' |
  while read deviceGuid; do 
    : 
  done
```

Note to MrTunaDeluxe:  `${var}` is different from `"$var"` -- you should prefer the latter. The first form is required for array element expansion, the various parameter substitutions, and also to disambiguate the variable from surrounding text (e.g. `echo "${var}text"`), but just using braces will not prevent word splitting or filename expansions.